# Search not showing recent results?

Tags: email, search, microsoft-outlook-2013

When I search for an email in outlook 2013, usually searching by person I received it from or by attachment, the most recent email the search will show me is from about two months back. It doesn't matter if I'm using a keyword or a person's name, the date on the "most recent" result is September even if I know I've emailed the same person or included the keyword in an email since then. From there the results progress backwards chronologically fine, but the results skip everything between now and September.

I did some googling around and most people seem to have problems getting outlook to show emails from over 12 months ago. That's solvable [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2733062) but I'm having trouble finding anything about a search that regularly doesn't include recent months even if I know recent emails apply to the search. Any assistance on this is appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked your Outlook Indexing?

If it states that there is an index directory, try removing and re-adding your outlook indexing.

Comment: would you mind directing how to do that? I got into Outlook Options > Search > Indexing Options > Advanced Options, is the "delete and rebuild index" button the one that will remove and re-add my index?

Comment: Yes that will remove your index, and it is just a case of going back to the indexing page and there should be a new/set up button.
What version of outlook are you using?

Comment: ok I gave it a shot, i selected a new location for re-adding the index, hit the "delete and rebuild index" and restarted the program, but search results are still coming up as only recent as september

Comment: Ok, open up task manager, go to the services tab, and find WSearch, check if that service is running and let me know.

Comment: Yes, WSearch is running

Comment: Ok can you stop the service, then go back to outlook and try searching again, this should fail or come up with an error message. close your outlook and any MS related programs. Restart the WSearch service and try to search again in outlook

Comment: I don't think it's working. I stopped the WSearch service, search came up with a fail as you said, so I closed outlook and othes MS related programs. After restarted the WSearch service I opened up outlook again and tried searching. It's still not pulling any results from the last two months even if I specifically search for an email/attachment within that time frame.

Comment: Is your outlook currently in Cached or online mode?

Comment: I believe it's currently in cached mode. I went into File > Account Settings > Email > Change and the "use cached exchange mode" was checked on.

Comment: Ok try searching when in "Online" mode, so turn off chached exchange mode.

Comment: That worked!! search results come up with recent emails, thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, I hope you have a good day

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem using Outlook 2013, and I'm not sure it's fixed yet.  However, here are some resources to try:

- Turn off Cached Exchange Mode (per the comments from A Hawkins) - this may fix the issue at the cost of making everything slow.  When you restart Outlook, then turn Cached Exchange Mode back on, then restart Outlook again, it might all work.
- Check the response about "Index Encrypted Files" here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eab3da2a-b1db-4c58-a169-fc0ddbc96154/outlook-2016-search-not-working-in-cached-exchange-mode?forum=outlook
- Check the response about Indexing Options here: https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/432870-searching-in-outlook-2013-using-cached-exchange-mode